# Pascal Text Menu Music Player

Tags: pascal

I need help with creating my music player, I'm receiving the same error and can't seem to get past it. Thank you.
I've attached my code below, as well as my errors.

Errors:

> Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.4 [2014/02/26] for i386 Copyright (c)
>    1993-2014 by Florian Klaempfl and others Target OS: Darwin for i386
>   Compiling MusicPlayer.pas
>
> MusicPlayer.pas(82,37) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "ShortString", expected "Album"
>
> MusicPlayer.pas(138,31) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got
>    "albumArray", expected "Album"
>
> MusicPlayer.pas(164,44) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "albumArray", expected "Album"
>
> MusicPlayer.pas(174) Fatal: There were 3 errors compiling module,
>   stopping Fatal: Compilation aborted Error: /usr/local/bin/ppc386
>   returned an error exitcode (normal if you did not specify a source
>   file to be compiled)

```
    program MusicPlayer;
uses TerminalUserInput;

type
    Track = record
       trackName: String;
       location: String;
    end;

    TrackArray = array of Track;

    Album = record
       albumName: String;
       artistName: String;
       genre: String;
       track: TrackArray;
       // key: Integer;
       trackNum: Integer;
       fileName: String;
    end;

    albumArray = array of Album;


function GetAlbums(): albumArray;
var
    // anAlbum: Album;
    //albums: albumArray;
    fileName: String;
    myFile: TextFile;
    numOfAlb: Integer;
    trackNum: Integer;
    i: Integer;
    j: Integer;
begin
    fileName := ReadString('Enter filename: ');
    AssignFile(myFile, fileName);
    // AssignFile(myFile, 'albums.dat');
    Reset(myFile);
    ReadLn(myFile, numOfAlb);
    setLength(result, numOfAlb);
    for i:= 0 to High(result) do
    begin
        ReadLn(myFile, result[i].albumname);
        ReadLn(myFile, result[i].artistName);
        ReadLn(myFile, result[i].genre);
        ReadLn(myFile, trackNum);
        setLength(result[i].track, trackNum);
        for j:= 0 to trackNum -1 do
        begin
            ReadLn(myFile, result[i].track[j].trackName);
            ReadLn(myFile, result[i].track[j].location);
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure DisplayAlbum(a: Album);
var
    //t: Track;
    i: Integer;

begin
    WriteLn('Album name is: ', a.albumName);
    WriteLn('Album artist name is: ', a.artistName);
    WriteLn('Album genre is: ', a.genre);
    WriteLn('Number of tracks are: ', a.trackNum);
    for i:= 0 to High(a.track) do
    begin
        WriteLn('Track name is: ', a.track[i].trackName);
        WriteLn('Album name is: ', a.track[i].location);
    end;
end;


function PrintAllGenres(albums: albumArray): albumArray;
var
    i: Integer;

begin
    for i := 0 to High(albums) do
    begin
        DisplayAlbum(albums[i].genre);
    end;

end;



procedure SelectAlbum(const albums: albumArray);
var
   val: Integer;
   i: Integer;
begin
   WriteLn('<< Welcome to the Track Player >>');
   val := ReadInteger('Enter an Album''s key number: ');
   for i := 0 to High(albums) do
   begin
     WriteLn('Album is now playing.');
   end;
   if (i > High(albums)) then
   begin
      WriteLn('Album was not found, now returning to Main Menu ');
   end;
end;

function UpdateAlbum(a: Album): Album;
begin
    a.albumName := ReadString('Please enter a new name for this album: ');
    a.genre := ReadString('Please enter a new genre for this album: ');
end;

// function UpdateAlbums(): albumArray;
// var
//    val: Integer;
//    i: Integer;
// begin
//    WriteLn('<< Album Updater >>');
//    val := ReadInteger('Enter an Album''s key number: ');
//    if (val = True) then
//         WriteLn('Album was found.')
//    else
//           WriteLn('Album was not found, now returning to Main Menu ');
// end;


procedure DisplayAlbums(albums: albumArray);
var
    val: Integer;
begin
   repeat
    WriteLn('<< Displaying Albums >>');
    WriteLn('1. Display all albums');
    WriteLn('2. Display genre');
    WriteLn('3. Return to main menu');
    val := ReadInteger('Enter a number to enter menu: ');

    case val of
        1: DisplayAlbum(albums);
        2: PrintAllGenres(albums);
    end;

  until val = 3;
end;


procedure Main();
var
    albums: albumArray;
    val: Integer;
begin
    repeat
        WriteLn('<< Text Music Player Menu >>');
        WriteLn('1. Read in Albums');
        WriteLn('2. Display Albums');
        WriteLn('3. Select an Album to play');
        WriteLn('4. Update an existing Album');
        WriteLn('5. Quit');
        val := ReadInteger('Enter a number to enter menu: ');

        case val of
            1: albums := GetAlbums();
            2: DisplayAlbums(albums);
            3: SelectAlbum(albums);
            4: albums := UpdateAlbum(albums);

        end;

    until val = 5;
end;

begin
    Main();
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have written

```
procedure DisplayAlbum(a: Album);
```

which means that you need to pass an `Album` to the procedure, but on line 82 you have written

```
    DisplayAlbum(albums[i].genre);
```

`genre` is a field of an `Album` while you should pass a whole `Album`

Change line 82 to

```
    DisplayAlbum(albums[i]);
```

I leave the other errors for you yourself to work out, the errors are very similar, and you should now be able to sort them out.
As I told you yesterday, you may want to (or actually, need to) speak with your tutor to get a better understanding.

Comment: Bravo, @Tom, +1, for suggesting that the OP actually speaks to his tutor about this - imo, it should happen far more often with these coursework problems posted on SO.  This one, the "Album Project" has appeared on SO a number of times and it seems to me that if those responsible knew a bit more about the problems their student have, they might do a better job of teaching the material in the first place.  Can live in hope I guess ...

Comment: Thanks @Martyn Yes, I think a gentle push in the right direction together with an example of how to solve one of several problems, might eventually bear fruit. And certainly the courseware sellers should take bigger responsibility. I just don't know them really, their names seldom popup here.

Comment: Fwiw, I did manage to track one of them back to its source recently, which turned out to be an Australian college.  They provided a supporting Unit with some custom routines including an oddly named one that enabled google to track it down.

Comment: @Martyn Ah ok. I guess there are serious ones too, hopefully most of them. Yet, sometimes the thaugths creep in, like "Thanx for mony, here your dox, codes and zertificatum, Good luck!"